# xPath selectSingleNode не могу выбрать элемент

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser, xpath

Добрый день. есть XML файл

```
<issuance xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" sender="35">
    <general>
        <number>35</number>
        <dateIssuance>2016-12-22</dateIssuance>
        <dateTransaction>2016-12-10</dateTransaction>
        <documentType>ORIGINAL</documentType>
    </general>
    <seller>
          //тут тоже есть поля и т.д.
    </seller>
</issuance>
```

Передаю в метод загруженый xml документ и пытаюсь получить значения полей

```
XmlNode doc = docs;
XmlNode selectNodeGeneral = doc.SelectSingleNode("/issuance/general");
elnVat.number = selectNodeGeneral.SelectSingleNode("number").InnerText;
elnVat.dateIssuance = selectNodeGeneral.SelectSingleNode("dateIssuance").InnerText;
```

но строчка `XmlNode selectNodeGeneral = doc.SelectSingleNode("/issuance/general");`возвращaет null, если убрать `xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" sender="35"`и оставить только ` то код начинает  работать.
Подскажите как мне быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указывать полное имя ноды, вместе с namespace, через `XmlNamespaceManager`, примерно так:

```
// считая, что docs - это XmlDocument

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(docs.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("w3s", "http://www.w3schools.com");

XmlNode doc = docs;
XmlNode selectNodeGeneral = doc.SelectSingleNode("/w3s:issuance/w3s:general", ns);
elnVat.number = selectNodeGeneral.SelectSingleNode("w3s:number", ns).InnerText;
elnVat.dateIssuance = selectNodeGeneral.SelectSingleNode("w3s:dateIssuance", ns).InnerText;
```

Comment: не проверял вживую, но должно работать :)

Comment: Дружище,огромное тебе спасибо. Работает,сейчас весь код изменю и можно идти спать.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNode doc = docs;
XmlNode selectNodeGeneral = doc.SelectSingleNode("//issuance/general/number");
elnVat.number = selectNodeGeneral.InnerText;
selectNodeGeneral = doc.SelectSingleNode("//issuance/general/dateIssuance");
elnVat.dateIssuance= selectNodeGeneral.InnerText;
```